# Can´t add new paragraphs to a Jasper Report document after build pressing ENTER key

Tags: jasper-reports

I need to generate a jasper document that is editable by the user **after build** using the Microsoft Word. The problem I encounter is that once I generate the document, I can not add new paragraphs between the existing ones using the **ENTER** key. What happens is that the text **disappears behind** the subsequent paragraphs, hiding under.

I tried using the overflow property and stretch with no results.

**EDIT** (clarification from a comment): GenericJon response is useful but, Could be this Microsoft Word property be setted when building the document with jasper exporter in order to open the document with this cell height property setted?

Thanks in advance!

My java application uses **jasperreports-4.5.1.jar**
I´m compiling my template with **Jaspersoft iReport Designer 5.0.4**
I use **Microsoft Word 2013** to edit the document after build.

Here is the XML report :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="SolicitudPresupuestoCM" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="475" leftMargin="60" rightMargin="60" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" whenResourceMissingType="Key" uuid="255a457f-fbfa-4352-8d45-fb04f539febb">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.2396694214876032"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.scriptlethandling" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.encoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    <import value="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.*"/>
    <import value="java.util.*"/>
    <import value="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.*"/>
    <parameter name="DIRECTORIO_IMAGENES" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false"/>
    <parameter name="fechaPropuesta" class="java.util.Date" isForPrompting="false"/>
    <parameter name="numParrafosPrimerTexto" class="java.lang.Integer" isForPrompting="false"/>
    <parameter name="nombreFirma" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false"/>
    <parameter name="cargoFirma" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false"/>
    <parameter name="expediente" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false"/>
    <parameter name="objeto" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false"/>
    <parameter name="aplicacionPresupuestaria" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false"/>
    <parameter name="importe" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false"/>
    <parameter name="empresa" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false"/>
    <parameter name="cif" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false"/>
    <parameter name="numFactura" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false"/>
    <queryString language="SQL">
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="texto" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <variable name="index" class="java.lang.Integer" incrementType="Report">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[Integer.valueOf($V{index}.intValue() + 1)]]></variableExpression>
        <initialValueExpression><![CDATA[Integer.valueOf(0)]]></initialValueExpression>
    </variable>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="101" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="false">
                <reportElement uuid="dfc390b7-4917-47da-970f-d9e69de9626d" x="355" y="79" width="121" height="14"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="8" pdfFontName="Arial" pdfEncoding="Cp1252" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{expediente}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="23" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" pattern="" isBlankWhenNull="false">
                <reportElement uuid="4fb4251a-765e-47b6-bd8d-60690d8df47a" x="0" y="0" width="475" height="10" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Justified">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="11" pdfEncoding="Cp1252" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{texto}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
        <band height="73" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="d0ec9d8d-de99-4b1f-a5f2-bd43b7ddd478" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="0" y="0" width="221" height="14" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[Boolean.valueOf(($V{index} == $P{numParrafosPrimerTexto}))]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="11" pdfFontName="Arial" pdfEncoding="Cp1252" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[OBJECT: Payment of the invoice number]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="f8151046-97b5-452c-9423-50eea1b9f5d3" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="0" y="14" width="60" height="14" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[Boolean.valueOf(($V{index} == $P{numParrafosPrimerTexto}))]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="11" pdfFontName="Arial" pdfEncoding="Cp1252" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[AMOUNT:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="2fa9090a-0ecd-4084-8947-48bfc161bd16" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="0" y="28" width="73" height="15" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[Boolean.valueOf(($V{index} == $P{numParrafosPrimerTexto}))]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="11" pdfFontName="Arial" pdfEncoding="Cp1252" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[APLICATION:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="3abdff65-88a4-4201-af12-2d89c9e9b2cd" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="0" y="43" width="100" height="15" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[Boolean.valueOf(($V{index} == $P{numParrafosPrimerTexto}))]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="11" pdfFontName="Arial" pdfEncoding="Cp1252" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[BIDDER:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="eecdd67b-eb52-47e3-ae9e-fd5be9f0578e" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="335" y="43" width="47" height="15" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[Boolean.valueOf(($V{index} == $P{numParrafosPrimerTexto}))]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="11" pdfFontName="Arial" pdfEncoding="Cp1252" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[NIF/CIF:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="false">
                <reportElement uuid="45e2af4d-aa76-4d8a-b736-09b9298b24c1" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="60" y="14" width="415" height="14" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[Boolean.valueOf(($V{index} == $P{numParrafosPrimerTexto}))]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="11" pdfFontName="Arial" pdfEncoding="Cp1252" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{importe}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="false">
                <reportElement uuid="0a69cee5-7970-4972-9b74-ebc4fe6687d5" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="77" y="28" width="306" height="15" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[Boolean.valueOf(($V{index} == $P{numParrafosPrimerTexto}))]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="11" pdfFontName="Arial" pdfEncoding="Cp1252" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{aplicacionPresupuestaria}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="false">
                <reportElement uuid="ea832f4b-30cd-4240-84dd-c39a01674540" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="100" y="43" width="235" height="15" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[Boolean.valueOf(($V{index} == $P{numParrafosPrimerTexto}))]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="11" pdfFontName="Arial" pdfEncoding="Cp1252" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{empresa}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="false">
                <reportElement uuid="291d18a5-4e09-41af-81ef-38da536f868b" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="383" y="43" width="92" height="15" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[Boolean.valueOf(($V{index} == $P{numParrafosPrimerTexto}))]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="11" pdfFontName="Arial" pdfEncoding="Cp1252" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{cif}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement uuid="15cc14e4-06ec-4c5f-92ff-5f7261bc83f8" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="221" y="0" width="58" height="14" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[Boolean.valueOf(($V{index} == $P{numParrafosPrimerTexto}))]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="11" pdfFontName="Arial" pdfEncoding="Cp1252" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{numFactura}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="9e5ab1d9-008f-44c5-b25a-c95184f1ff1b" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="279" y="0" width="86" height="14" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[Boolean.valueOf(($V{index} == $P{numParrafosPrimerTexto}))]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="11" pdfFontName="Arial" pdfEncoding="Cp1252" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[realtive to]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="false">
                <reportElement uuid="7c57f57d-033d-4e85-8f18-d2f40521e5b3" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="365" y="0" width="110" height="14" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[Boolean.valueOf(($V{index} == $P{numParrafosPrimerTexto}))]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="11" pdfFontName="Arial" pdfEncoding="Cp1252" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{objeto}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
        <band height="85" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="false">
                <reportElement uuid="386f28db-aa1e-46e8-8c31-dd01a5c041c8" x="0" y="20" width="475" height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[Boolean.valueOf(($V{index} == $P{numParrafosPrimerTexto}))]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="11" pdfEncoding="Cp1252" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{cargoFirma}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="d4e52606-aaf0-48a8-8dd3-b1532b0f5eed" key="staticText" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="0" y="0" width="135" height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[Boolean.valueOf(($V{index} == $P{numParrafosPrimerTexto}))]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="11" pdfEncoding="Cp1252" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Somewhere,]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="false">
                <reportElement uuid="a8ceb09b-bc70-4875-90de-877cf9889351" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="0" y="65" width="475" height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[Boolean.valueOf(($V{index} == $P{numParrafosPrimerTexto}))]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="11" pdfEncoding="Cp1252" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{nombreFirma}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" isBlankWhenNull="false">
                <reportElement uuid="71a758b9-a5bc-4890-ae2f-74263245d0c4" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="135" y="0" width="220" height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[Boolean.valueOf(($V{index} == $P{numParrafosPrimerTexto}))]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="11" pdfEncoding="Cp1252" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{fechaPropuesta}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="122">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="47118a66-c23c-4b35-b90f-7e469eb97a99" key="staticText" x="0" y="0" width="73" height="20"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="11" pdfEncoding="Cp1252" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Otherwhere,]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="880fd5a8-8a35-49d2-b226-5413d7d02120" key="staticText" x="0" y="20" width="475" height="20"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="11" pdfEncoding="Cp1252" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[The director of ...]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="6a5f6b70-0574-4c6f-8e44-09356eda2a51" key="staticText" x="0" y="71" width="475" height="20"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="11" pdfEncoding="Cp1252" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Charles Irwin]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </pageFooter>
</jasperReport>
```

Here is the result document that I should easily customize after build.
[Go to download document](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B14tJs_XpZzjQm4zOExGOW1tSWc/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The row will re-size when you write to it, when you add the net.sf.jasperreports.export.docx.flexible.row.height property to the report with the true value.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport ...>
<property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
<property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
<property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.docx.flexible.row.height" value="true"/>
```

More Info about property:
[Link](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/config.reference.html#net.sf.jasperreports.export.docx.flexible.row.height)

NOTE: you should think on paradigm, that reports are "read only". So users should fill data into some programmatic form and afterwards the reports is generated ...

Comment: Great!!!! This was exactly what I was looking for!! Lots of thanks! About the note, I fill the form n a programmatic manner but users still want to make some changes afterwards easily.

Answer (score 1):

JasperReports achieves the layout of the document by using a table. In MS Word, you should be able to see this by selecting *Table Tools > Layout > Show Gridlines*. All of the rows have a specific fixed height, so when you add more content beyond the size of a cell, it will not be visible.

To enable the cells to grow as you add new paragraphs, right-click inside the cell you want to add content to, and select **Table Properties...**. On the **Row** tab, un-check the box next to **Specify Height**. The row height should then increase to accommodate the contents.

Comment: I really appreciate your response but in my original XML file I don´t have a table element so I can´t open such "Table Properties...". Is there any other way to achieve this withouth add a table element to my report ? Changes to be made over the XML file will be very useful. :(

Comment: You misunderstand. You do not need to add a table to your report. This is a change to resultDoc.docx and must be made in MS Word. It is the behaviour of the JasperReports docx exporter to add the report elements to a table on export, and you cannot change this by making a modification to your report.

Comment: OK, I understand what you mean right now but I´m looking for a solution to be applied in the jasper doc cause this are the client requirements. They only want to write directly the paragraph like whe you write an standard word document with no Word configurations... Thanks after all